# Creating type based on object values in an array JSON in TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript

I have a JSON file that has a format something like this:

```json
[
    {
        "foo1": "bar1",
        "something": "",
        "else": ""
    },
    {
        "foo2": "bar2",
        "something": "",
        "else": ""
    },
    ...
]
```

and I want to create a type with only the "bar" values i.e. the values of the foos of all the objects in the list.

I want to create a type that produces the following:

```
type bars = "bar1" | "bar2" | "bar3" | //...
```

but I have no idea where to even start. How do I traverse through that list and only return the values, then store them in a type?

Edit: I made a mistake. The JSON file actually looks more like this:

```json
[
    {
        "foo": "bar1",
        "something": "",
        "else": ""
    },
    {
        "foo": "bar2",
        "something": "",
        "else": ""
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: From which keys are you supposed to infer the union type from?

Comment: @Terry I'm not sure what you mean. Could you elaborate, or perhaps use simpler language? I'm not very advanced at Typescript yet.

Comment: In your original question you are trying to infer a union type from different keys "foo1" and "foo2", but I can see you've updated your question. With the same key "foo" it's much easier and simpler to get the union type you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can define your data `as const` then you can easily infer the union type of the `foo` key using mapped types:

```
const data = [
    {
        "foo": "bar1",
        "something": "",
        "else": ""
    },
    {
        "foo": "bar2",
        "something": "",
        "else": ""
    },
] as const;

// Expected: type bars = "bar1" | "bar2"
type bars = typeof data[number]['foo'];
```

See example on [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAsAKBvmAb1wNJgCIAzEEcgLgoCMEAnARnIBoSz9yIQAWwCmUABYBLMAHN6FLj17lhAGwjC55copgBfbngLFDS6rQblmLAEwKTZfkNGSZmu7z6r1bnftwBdGAQIGFBIKABuXFwAehiYAFEADwAHYWAoYTgGKABPNJgrEPRLVg4YAB8mVltcPIKitBh64RBKeCQEDDAAV0FGYRZ-DAByMxH-CKA).